# Porting from one Json to javas org.json.JSONObject, missing keys not acting the same

Tags: c#, java, json

I have code in a method that I ported that now throws JSONException in my newly created java code.

Below does not work as it used to:

```
    if (theEvent.getString("plugin")== null)
    {
        processNonPluginEvent(theEvent);
        return;
    }
```

I found out using

```
org.json.JSONObject
```

behaves differently than it did on my old code using a different JSON library in c#.  The above code always gets caught by an exception.  In my old code if a key didn't exist it would return null.  Do I really have to catch for that exception in the event the key doesn't exsist?  or is there another way I have not yet discovered to tell if my org.json.JSONObject has a key or not in it?

for reference the old c# code looked like:

```
  if (theEvent["plugin"] == null)
  {
       processNonPluginEvent(theEvent);
       return;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using the code from [this library](http://www.json.org/java/), I believe you want:

```
if (!theEvent.has("plugin"))
{
    processNonPluginEvent(theEvent);
    return;
}
```

Check out the documentation for the `JSONObject` class:

http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html

Also, all classes from the library are documented [here](http://www.json.org/java/).

Answer (score 1):

To see if the `JSONObject` has a key, use the `JSONObject.has(String key)` function.

e.g.

```
if (!theEvent.has("plugin")) {
    processNonPluginEvent(theEvent);
}
```

From the JavaDoc, the `has()` function:

> Determine if the JSONObject contains a
>   specific key.